# PHP +SIlex+Mysql deciding on the type of used form by query

Tags: php, forms, silex

I've got this little problem (I'm a beginner coder and not an English native speaker, so please forgive my stupidity) and I'm humbly asking for your help. I'm coding a surveying system. Depending on the type of the question a survey-creator chooses to make (closed or open), I want this Form to display either choice or textarea.
I don't really know how to do such a thing, and if 'ifs' in forms are even possible. (Please don't send me to the documentation page, it's dark and full of corpses out there). Rough code below.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

            ->add(
                'answers',
                'choice', 
                array(
                    'choices'  => $this->xxx($this->app),
                    'expanded' => false

                )
            )

            ->add(
                'answers',
                'textarea',

         if (question.type == 'closed'){

         }else{

         }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's going to be impossible for you to accomplish this without reading the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/index.html). This is a fairly advanced topic that involves a few different aspects of the Symfony `FormBuilderInterface` and will likely require both server-side `php` and client-side `javascript`.

What you are doing seems similar to what is explained in [Dynamic Generation for Submitted Forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#dynamic-generation-for-submitted-forms). This approach uses **event listeners** with a **form modifier** function.

You could for example modify the form upon the POST_SET_DATA event adding additional fields based on the data from another field.

Here is a skeleton buildForm method that shows all the available event listeners:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $options = array('open','closed');
    $choices = array('choice a','choice b','choice c');

    $builder
        ->add('answer_option', 'choice', 
            array(
                'choices'  => $options,
                'expanded' => true 
            )
        )
        ->add('answer_choices', 'choice', 
            array(
                'choices'  => $choices,
                'expanded' => false
            )
        )
        ->add('answer_textarea', 'textarea')
        ->add('submit', 'submit')
    ;

    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
        error_log(print_r('PRE_SET_DATA',1).' '.__FILE__.' '.__LINE__.PHP_EOL,0);
        $data = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();
    });

    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
        error_log(print_r('POST_SET_DATA',1).' '.__FILE__.' '.__LINE__.PHP_EOL,0);
        $data = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();
    });

    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) {
        error_log(print_r('PRE_SUBMIT',1).' '.__FILE__.' '.__LINE__.PHP_EOL,0);
        $data = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();
    });

    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) {
        error_log(print_r('SUBMIT',1).' '.__FILE__.' '.__LINE__.PHP_EOL,0);
        $data = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();
    });

    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) {
        error_log(print_r('POST_SUBMIT',1).' '.__FILE__.' '.__LINE__.PHP_EOL,0);
        $data = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();
    });
}
```